# Communicate between http4s backend and Binding.scala frontend

Tags: scala, scala.js, http4s, binding.scala

I'm trying to use Binding.scala with an existing http4s backend service, but kind of lost on how they would fit together. I'm not sure how to "bind" a say fs2 `Task` or cats-effect `IO` with Binding.scala.

Answer (score 0):

I never used http4s, but a hint could be to use [FutureBinding](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala#remote-data-binding-for-scalaconcurrentfuture-futurebindingscala).

As long as you get a Future you can use that quite nicely:

Here my example for calling an async webservice (ajax-call):

```
  @dom def afClients(): Binding[HTMLElement] = {
    val apiPath = s"/calendar/afClients"

    FutureBinding(Ajax.get(apiPath))
      .bind match {
      case None =>
        <div class="ui active inverted dimmer front">
          <div class="ui large text loader">Loading</div>
        </div>
      case Some(Success(response)) =>
        val json = Json.parse(response.responseText)
        info(s"Json received List[AFClientConfig]: ${json.toString().take(20)}")
        json.validate[List[AFClientConfig]] match {
          case JsSuccess(u, _) =>
            changeAFClients(u)
            <div>
            </div>
          case JsError(errors) =>
            <div>
              {s"Problem parsing User: ${errors.map(e => s"${e._1} -> ${e._2}")}"}
            </div>
        }

      case Some(Failure(exception)) =>
        error(exception, s"Problem accessing $apiPath")
        <div>
          {exception.getMessage}
        </div>
    }
  }
```